# Hardhar Deploy solidity smart contract using onClick event in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solidity, hardhat

I would like to deploy my contract in frontend after a user click on a button. In hardhat documentation, I would have to normally run `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js` in my terminal to deploy. Is it possible to deploy in the frontend?

The code below is something I would like to do.

```js
const hre = require("hardhat")   // this will cause error 
const deployClick = async () => {
      setIsNoClicked(true);
      const ticketContract = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Greeter");
      const ticket = await ticketContract.deploy("Hello, Hardhat!");
      await ticket.deployed();
      console.log("Ticket Contract deployed to:", ticket.address);
    }
```

Comment: Deployment transaction is not different from any other transaction, so there is no reason you could not do it.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa But running in terminal is different from calling it in the frontend and I have no idea how to do it

Comment: @Leo I have the same problem. Did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: @Nina I eventually ditched hardhat. There's a metamask tutorial where you can easily deploy a contract via metamask but I've lost the link